# How do I put information not in a table into a dataframe from web scraping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import re

towns = pd.DataFrame()

town_names = [f"Abbeville-Alabama",
f"Abernant-Alabama",
f"Alpine-Utah",
f"Dixon-Montana",
f"Adak-Alaska",]

for town_name in town_names:
    page = requests.get(f"https://www.city-data.com/city/{town_name}.html").text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    print(town_name)
    sex_population = str(doc.find(id="population-by-sex"))
    (males, females) = [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"(?<=\()[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=\%\))", sex_population)]
    print(males, females)

    # poverty_level = str(doc.find(id="poverty-level"))
    # broke = float(re.findall("(<?<\/b> )[0-9]*.[0-9]*", poverty_level))
    # print(broke)

    # religion_population = str(doc.find(id="religion"))
    # atheist = float(re.findall("(?<=None<\/td><td>)[0-9,]*(?=<\/td><td>)", religion_population)[0].replace(",", ""))
    # print(atheist)

    total_population = str(doc.find(id="city-population"))
    residents = float(re.findall("(?<=</b> )[0-9]*", total_population)[0].replace(",", ""))
    print(residents)

    religion_population = doc.find(id="religion").find_all('tr')
    data = []
    for row in religion_population:
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        if columns:
            religion = columns[0].get_text(strip=True)
            number = columns[1].get_text(strip=True).replace(",", "").replace("-","0")
            print(f'religion: {religion} | number: {number}')
            data.append([religion, int(number)])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['religion', 'number'])
    df['percentage'] = (df['number'] / df['number'].sum()) * 100
    atheist=df[df.religion == "None"].iloc[0]["percentage"]
    evangelicals = df[df.religion == "Evangelical Protestant"].iloc[0]["percentage"]
    print(atheist)
    print(evangelicals)

    education_population = doc.find(id="education-info").find_all('b')
    data = []
    for row in education_population:
        columns = row.find_all('b')
        if columns:
            education = columns[0].get_text(strip=True)
            ed_number = columns[1].get_text(strip=True).replace(",", "").replace("-", "0")
            print(f'education: {education} | number: {ed_number}')
            data.append([education, int(ed_number)])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['education', 'number'])
    df['percentage'] = (df['number'] / df['number'].sum()) * 100
    phds = df[df.education == "Graduate or professional degree"].iloc[0]["percentage"]
    highschoolgrads = df[df.education == "High school or higher"].iloc[0]["percentage"]
    print(phds)
    print(highschoolgrads)

    print("\n")
```

How do I get the education information into a dataframe? I'm attempting to organize the values into education level and percentage.

Also any idea why when I try to cast poverty level as a float in broke, it says it can't because it's a list?

At this point I'm just typing so that stackoverflow will allow me to post because it thinks I don't have enough details. SO... if anyone is interested what this is for I'm doing a datamining/machine learning project where it's going to take the scores from the HRC's municipality equality index and the info about the cities scored and try to learn how to estimate the score of cities which haven't been scored. It's my first machine learning project ever. I worry that I've picked something too big for my first time but I'm really already committed to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the scraper.

In education, in the URL it seems that the values are in a `list` element `li` and the `title/label` is in `b` inside  `li` .
In the scraper, you are just collecting the `b` tags, soo you're missing the `required numeric value`. You can change that to make it work.
Thanks!